# asymptotic expansion of hermite functions

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Does anybody know how to proof the first asymptotic expansion of this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Asymptotic_expansion ?
(and how the physicist use this asymptotic expansion ?)

I try to use the expression of $H_n$, the Hermite polynomial:

$ H_n(x)= \frac{i^n e^{x^2}}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{R}t^n e^{-t^2/4}e^{-ixt}dt$ with the Laplace's method like for the asymptotic expansion of $H_n(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2n}}) $ but I failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any work so far?

Comment: I edited my first post to discribe what I tried.

Comment: did the link http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_508.htm not make it obvious?

Comment: There's no easier (or shortest) proof ? It's hard to read the proof with all these parameters. And I don't really understand how the Bessel functions appear.

Comment: It's derived in considerable detail in Szegő's book *Orthogonal Polynomials*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read this book.